# Angular – shareReplay not caching data

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs

I have an Angular service which should get a large object from backend and cache it indefinitely. I don't want subsequent HTTP calls. It looks something like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
    data$: Observable<MyData>;

    constructor(apiService: SomeApiService) {
        this.data$ = of(new MyData()).pipe(
            switchMap(c => apiService.get().pipe(shareReplay(1)))
        )
    }

    // used by a route resolver, which should execute the first (and ONLY) HTTP request:
    get dataLoaded$(): Observable<boolean> { 
        return this.data$.pipe(
            map(d => !!d)
        );
    }
}
```

What I **thought** this does is:

1. Start with an empty `MyData` object so the app doesn't break before HTTP request resolves
2. Switch to the result of `apiService.get()` once it emits, cache it and turn it into a hot `Observable` using `shareReplay(1)`

Instead, each time a component using the service is constructed, a new HTTP call is sent.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shareReplay is not at the right place:

Your version:

```
constructor(apiService: SomeApiService) {
    this.data$ = of(new MyData()).pipe(
        switchMap(c => apiService.get().pipe(shareReplay(1)))
    )
}
```

How it should be

```
constructor(apiService: SomeApiService) {
    this.data$ = of(new MyData()).pipe(
        switchMap(c => apiService.get()),
        shareReplay(1)
    )
}
```

The reason for this is because the only thing you were sharing was the observable returned by `apiService.get()`. Therefore, if you had 2 subscribers to `this.data$` it'd create the whole stream 2 times.

If you move the `shareReplay` as the very last operator of the whole stream, then the entire stream is shared, enforcing only 1 subscription of everything that is above it.